# How to make slice with dynamic size/length/capacity

Tags: arrays, go, slice, goland

I seem to be able to create a slice with dynamic size/capacity/length/whatever using:

```
cleaned := []interface{}{}
```

how can I do the same with `make()`?  I tried this:

```
cleaned := make([]interface{})
```

but it wants me to include a length?

> Missing len argument to make

Comment: If you want an empty slice, then you don't need to use make. Why do you think make is required?

Comment: jetbrains complains and says `Empty slice declaration via literal` and suggests replacing with `var cleaned []interface{}` , but it's unclear why?

Comment: Jet brains is trying to hint that you should leave it nil if it’s empty.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman: Your Jetbrains question is a differnt question. On Stack Overflow, you should open a new question. (See my revised answer for the why.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two method:

1. Using `cleaned := make([]interface{},0)` and than call `cleaned = append(cleaned, your_data)`
2. Declaring an empty array: `var cleaned []interface{}{}`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> cleaned := []interface{}{}
> ```
>
> how can I do the same with make()?

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    {
        cleaned := []interface{}{}
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned)
    }

    // OR

    {
        cleaned := make([]interface{}, 0)
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned)
    }

    // OR

    {
        cleaned := make([]interface{}, 0, 0)
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qndsxIKWjEp

Output:

```
0 0 []
0 0 []
0 0 []
```

Reference:

[The Go Programming Language Specificatio](https://golang.org/ref/spec)n : [Making slices, maps and channe](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

---

---

> Comment: jetbrains complains and says Empty slice declaration via
>   literal and suggests replacing with var cleaned []interface{} , but
>   it's unclear why? – Olegzandr Denman

---

That is a different question. The why is clear.

> [Go Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) : [Declaring Empty Slices](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#declaring-empty-slices)
>
> When declaring an empty slice, prefer
>
> ```
> var t []string
> ```
>
> over
>
> ```
> t := []string{}
> ```
>
> The former declares a nil slice value, while the latter is non-nil but
>   zero-length. They are functionally equivalent—their len and cap are
>   both zero—but the nil slice is the preferred style.
>
> . . .

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    {
        cleaned := []interface{}{}
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned, cleaned == nil)
    }

    // OR

    {
        cleaned := make([]interface{}, 0)
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned, cleaned == nil)
    }

    // OR

    {
        cleaned := make([]interface{}, 0, 0)
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned, cleaned == nil)
    }

    // OR

    {
        var cleaned []interface{}
        fmt.Println(len(cleaned), cap(cleaned), cleaned, cleaned == nil)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9cZOOS2F9qI

Output:

```
0 0 [] false
0 0 [] false
0 0 [] false
0 0 [] true
```